# Handle race conditions in javascript / cordova local storage when e.g. downloading files

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to download several files in parallel and save their urls into a dictionary which is stored in local storage. The callback looks like so:

```
function(entry) {
        var downloads = JSON.parse(global.storage.getItem('downloads'));
        downloads[dbid] = entry.toURL();
        console.log(downloads);
        global.storage.setItem('downloads', JSON.stringify(downloads));
    }
```

I was not expecting race conditions to happen as js is single threaded. But they do happen as the prints show. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a lock, something like this.

```
function addDownloadUrl(entry) {
    var lock = global.storage.getItem('downloads_lock')
    if (lock) {
        setTimeout(function(){ addDownloadUrl(entry) }, 500);
    } else {
        global.storage.setItem('downloads_lock', '1');
        var downloads = JSON.parse(global.storage.getItem('downloads'));
        downloads[dbid] = entry.toURL();
        console.log(downloads);
        global.storage.setItem('downloads', JSON.stringify(downloads));
        global.storage.removeItem('downloads_lock');
    }
}
```

Have not tested it, and you probably want to add some more safeguards, like if the lock isn't removed after X seconds because something went wrong in between.

Comment: I thought of something similar. I would still like to know where exactly the race conditions / multithreadedness comes from.